# Rails 3 custom domains for users on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm looking to set up custom domains for users. Much like Tumblr does.

I understand that the user must point their A record to an IP address. I found some information here: [Custom domains in a Rails App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926358/custom-domains-in-a-rails-app)

Can someone give me an example of this with a Heroku/Rails 3 setup? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you setup a wildcard DNS to point to your main app, you can use the `:subdomain` in `config/routes.rb` to handle your business logic.